# Program wont run right in Python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am trying to make a very simple program in python and was just attempting to try this out but I press f5 to run and then the program says that shape() is undefined. Here is my code:

```
import turtle

shape("turtle")
i=0
while i<360:
    circle(100)
    right(1)
    i+=1
```

Here are my logs when I press f5:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\coold\Documents\Coding\PythonStuff\turtle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import turtle
  File "C:\Users\coold\Documents\Coding\PythonStuff\turtle.py", line 3, in <module>
    shape("turtle")
NameError: name 'shape' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Yes. `shape` is *indeed not defined*. You probably meant `turtle.shape("turtle")`

Comment: Or alternatively, you may have intended to use `from turtle import *`, although that's kind of messy.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing turtle. shape, turtle.circle, and turtle.right in your code.

```
import turtle
turtle.shape("turtle")
i=0
while i<360:
    turtle.circle(100)
    turtle.right(1)
    i+=1
raw_input()
```

Comment: Not `raw_input()` but `turtle.exitonclick()` to keep it Python version independent.